# Solr - Why are scores of documents different although the query has not differentiated between them

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I have put the following queries below to get this response -

```js
"response":{"numFound":200,"start":0,"maxScore":20.458012,"docs":[
      {
        "food_group":"Dairy",
        "carbs":"13.635",
        "protein":"2.625",
        "name":"Apple Milkshake",
        "fat":"3.814",
        "id":"109",
        "calories":99.0,
        "_version_":1565386306583789568,
        "score":20.458012},
      {
        "food_group":"Proteins",
        "carbs":"4.79",
        "protein":"4.574",
        "name":"Chettinad Egg Curry",
        "fat":"6.876",
        "id":"526",
        "calories":99.0,
        "_version_":1565386306489417728,
        "score":19.107327}
.....//other documents...
]}
```

Querys -

```
q = (food_group:"Proteins"  OR
food_group:"Dairy"  OR
food_group:"Grains")

bf = div(1,abs(sub(100,calories)))^15
bq = food_group:"Proteins" + food_group:"Dairy" + food_group:"Grains"
```

My question is that even though i have not provided any boost to "Dairy" with respect to "Proteins" in `bq` why is the "Dairy" document having higher score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because "Dairy" is a more rare term in your corpus. Lucene will give a higher score to a match with a term that is rare vs a match with a very common term.

If you want to get into the detials, look up how [BM25](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html) similarity is computed. BM25 is what Lucene (thus Solr) uses now by default, before it was TD-IDF, but they are very similar.

Comment: Is there any way to make the score of both the documents same, that is can  this rareness factor be removed? @Persimmonium

Comment: You need to understand TF / IDF. TF is term frequency, IDF is I Document Frequency. Scoring depends on normalization calculations like this. There is a way to remove normalization from the calculations; look to remove it if you want.